# How to make a Butcher Tableau?

Tags: tables

I want to create a Butcher Tableau like [here in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Examples).

How do I do this? I only found an online tool for creating simple tables. But cannot make these Tableaus with it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `array` can handle it.  An `array` is like a `tabular`, but works in math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}
{c|cccc}
0\\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}\\
\frac{1}{2} &0 &\frac{1}{2} \\
1& 0& 0& 1\\
\hline
& \frac{1}{6} &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{3} &\frac{1}{6} 
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. But it seems that the website http://www.matheboard.de/formeleditor.php cannot display some of the functions. Is there a possibility to use it there? I thought it is a simple LaTex editor.

Comment: @ChrizZly It works for me there, if I copy/paste everything starting at `\renewcommand\arraystretch` up through `\end{array}`.  Note that the data box at that website is *already* in math mode, so I need not include the `\[` and `\]` which otherwise opens and closes math mode.

Comment: As I said. I am totally new to Tex. now it worked for me. Thank you!